# 403 Forbidden while trying to display image from url - Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to display image in kivy application, but image loader returns error 403 forbidden.

I noticed that I have to send User-Agent header to bypass this error, but i couldn't find any way to pass headers to image loader

Is there any way to solve this problem?

kv file

```
AsyncImage:
    source: 'url_to_image'
    keep_ratio: True
```

error:

```
[ERROR  ] [Loader      ] Failed to load image <url_to_image>
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't modify the User-Agent when using AsyncImage. The responsible code is [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/loader.py#L317):

```
fd = urllib_request.urlopen(filename)
```

As you see there is no good way to pass a different UserAgent in there.

Instead handle the download of the file yourself.

I guess you could also try to pass an `urllib.request.Request` object with a modified `split` method so that the variable `filename` does not actually contain a string but a `Request`, but still survives the checks of `StringProperty` (in `AsyncImage`). But that would probably be very unstable and not a "proper" solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know it's very bad idea, but I changed the kivy file, added headers to request and everything is working now.